# What is the difference between CookieContainer and Response.Cookies collection?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have been doing some research on this and I couldn't find a straight answer.

Are there some cookies stored in the container that I can't get to using the Response.Cookies collection? How are cookies handled between requests using these objects? Are some cookies stored in the container but not others?

Answer (score 8):

Judging by the tags you've used on this question, it looks like you're getting confused.

`CookieContainer` and `CookieCollection` are used with `HttpWebRequest` which is when your program is a HTTP client. `CookieCollection` stores cookies associated with a single domain name. `CookieContainer` stored all the cookies over all the domain names.

In ASP.NET, `HttpRequest.Cookies` is `HttpCookieCollection` and is used when your program is a HTTP server. It stores the cookies sent by the client to the server. Because there is only one domain name (i.e. yours) there is no need for a 2-dimensional collection.

The two sets of classes (`CookieContainer` and `CookieCollection` vs `HttpCookieCollection`) are totally unrelated with each other.

In this post I've provided some basic background on the cookie collection classes in .NET, but I don't understand your question. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Please provide a link to your post. I am just trying to understand the difference. I needed to log in to a site using these objects and carry through the session and authentication cookies for each requests. For some reason the CookieCollection did not contain any cookies but when I switched to CookieContainer it worked. I just wanted to understand why.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET question, or a HttpWebRequest question, or are you attempting to use HttpWebRequest from within an ASP.NET application?

Comment: I send a request using HttpWebRequest to a server and get back an HttpWebResponse. I can get to cookies using HttpWebResponse.Cookies and/or CookieContainer. This questions was intended to get a bit more insight into what the difference is between the two (if any) given this scenario. If there is no difference then why have both?